# understanding javascript behaviour

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this code in file getSel.js:

```
    if(sel){
        console.log("getSel.js: sel before :"+sel.toString());
    }
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    console.log("getSel.js: sel after :"+sel.toString());
```

the script runs using the code

```
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'getSel.js'});
```

from the background.js.
when the code runs , then the same string that was selected is prinited in the console in both "before" and "after".
I would excpect that in the first log I will see the string that was selected before.
How come that sel.toString() returns the selected string before the line

```
    var sel = window.getSelection();
```

is executed?

Comment: Does the above code run more than once? Is it invoked after some event is occurring?

Comment: Yes, it runs when I select text and click on an option that I added to the menu that pops when right clicking the selected text.

Comment: Why are you expecting it change? `window.getSelection()` is 'read-only'. Do you change the selection in between the executions?

Comment: yes, I select different text